# Mongoose async call to another model makes validation impossible

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express, mongoose

I have two mongoose Schemas which look like this:

```
var FlowsSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String},
    active: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    product: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'ClientProduct'},
    type: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'ConversionType'},
});
```

this schema is then embedded in a parent schema that looks like this:

```
var ClientCampaignSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String},
    active: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    activeFrom: {type: Date},
    activeUntil: {type: Date},
    client: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Client', required: true},
    flows: [FlowsSchema]
});
```

and

```
var ConversionTypeSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true},
    requiresProductAssociation: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});
```

As you can see my FlowsSchema holds a reference towards the ConversionType. What I want to do is only allow a product to be added to a flow, if the associated conversiontype's 'requiresProductAssociation' is equal to true.
Unfortunately, wether I use validators or middleware this would mean making a call to mongoose.model('ConversionType') which is automatically async and messes things up. What do?

p.s. if there would be a way  to store a reference to that requiresProductAssociation boolean rather than the entire object that would be great because I wouldn't need to make the async call to that model anymore,  but I don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for [`SchemaType#validate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate) describe how to perform asynchronous validation for cases like this.  An asynchronous validator function receives *two* arguments, the second being a callback function you call to asynchronously report whether the value is valid.

That lets you implement this validation as:

```
FlowsSchema.path('type').validate(function(value, respond) {
    mongoose.model('ConversionType').findById(value, function(err, doc) {
        respond(doc && doc.requiresProductAssociation);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's great except i forgot to mention one thing and I feel like this might be a big deal. My FlowsSchema is actually an embedded Schema of a bigger one that looks like this: `var ClientCampaignSchema = new Schema({
 name: {type: String, required: true},
 description: {type: String},
 active: {type: Boolean, default: false},
 activeFrom: {type: Date},
 activeUntil: {type: Date},
 client: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Client', required: true},
 flows: [FlowsSchema]
});`    If i use your solution, i get an infinite loop when saving a regular Campaign

Comment: @DanMoldovan This will still work even if `FlowsSchema` is embedded within a parent schema like that.  BTW, it would be better to edit the question to include that detail as code doesn't format well in comments.

Comment: I took your code and made it like this `ClientCampaignSchema.path('flows').validate(function (flows, respond) {
 if (flows.length > 0) {
  flows.forEach(function (flow) {
   mongoose.model('ConversionType').findById(flow.type, function (err, item) {
    respond(item && item.requiresProductAssociation);
   });
  });
 }
});` but I get an infinite loop when saving an object..

Comment: @DanMoldovan You shouldn't need to do that as Mongoose's validation is asynchronously recursive.  See the fifth bullet here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Comment: well I guess I might understand that, but if i call .validate on either 'flows.type' or 'type' path, I get a `Cannot call method 'validate' on undefined` error, I guess that's because type is not something that the parent Schema has, only the FlowsSchema

Comment: @DanMoldovan I think you're making this harder than it needs to be.  Calling `save` on a `ClientCampaign` doc will validate all of its fields, including the elements of `flows`, which ends up invoking the async validator for the `type` field of `FlowsSchema` for each element.